Failed to deploy in Azure
I have an spring boot appliction which using elastic search db
I am connecting to the bonsai elastic search cloud,
I was able run the application from local and it is using cloud elastic search
however I am not able to rung the appliction in azure server. I am using same configurations in the local but getting the following error,
2024-09-03T10:54:05.0281618Z Deleting container: uob-search-service_kudu_e31e787b. Retry count = 0
2024-09-03T10:54:09.6904143Z Container spec TerminationMessagePolicy  path
2024-09-03T10:54:09.7284369Z Container is terminated. Total time elapsed: 30137 ms.
2024-09-03T10:54:28.4775630Z Container is terminating. Grace period: 5 seconds.
2024-09-03T10:54:28.4919559Z Stop and delete container. Retry count = 0
2024-09-03T10:54:28.6257810Z Stopping container: uob-search-service_ceaff102.
2024-09-03T10:54:39.5042488Z Deleting container: uob-search-service_ceaff102. Retry count = 0
2024-09-03T10:54:40.2797980Z Container spec TerminationMessagePolicy  path
2024-09-03T10:54:40.2927995Z Container is terminated. Total time elapsed: 11813 ms./home/LogFiles/2024_09_03_10-30-0-187_default_docker.log  (https://uob-search-service-agb9g3axfdamfvc2.scm.southeastasia-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2024_09_03_10-30-0-187_default_docker.log)/home/LogFiles/2024_09_03_10-30-0-187_docker.log  (https://uob-search-service-agb9g3axfdamfvc2.scm.southeastasia-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2024_09_03_10-30-0-187_docker.log)
2024-09-03T02:55:20.725Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container uob-search-service_0_6309de40. Elapsed time = 125.074144 sec
2024-09-03T02:55:35.953Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container uob-search-service_0_6309de40. Elapsed time = 140.3909761 sec
2024-09-03T02:55:52.321Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container uob-search-service_0_6309de40. Elapsed time = 156.7588154 sec
2024-09-03T02:56:09.733Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container uob-search-service_0_6309de40. Elapsed time = 174.1709477 sec
2024-09-03T02:56:24.877Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container uob-search-service_0_6309de40. Elapsed time = 189.3152518 sec
2024-09-03T02:56:40.929Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container uob-search-service_0_6309de40. Elapsed time = 205.3676624 sec
2024-09-03T02:56:58.589Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container uob-search-service_0_6309de40. Elapsed time = 223.0272569 sec
2024-09-03T02:57:13.770Z ERROR - Container uob-search-service_0_6309de40 for site uob-search-service did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 238.20823 sec
2024-09-03T02:57:19.345Z ERROR - Container uob-search-service_0_6309de40 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.


Please help me . I am using Azure free version
